# Question about AdminDirectory.Orgunits.update method

Tags: google-apps-script

I've spent a better part of a day trying to figure out the correct JSON body and arguments to update an OU; I'm actually trying to rename an OU. I'm close but in any case, the solution has so far escaped me.

I've referenced these docs so far:

- https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits/update#http-request
- https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/admin_directory_v1.orgunits.html#update

I have tried a few variations on arguments in the object with parameters passed to AdminDirectory.Orgunits.update. Ultimately, there are no examples so I'm not 100% sure what the correct parameters are.

Here's my test function thus far as well:

```
function test_renameOU(){

  /* Args:
  customerId: string, Immutable ID of the G Suite account (required)
  orgUnitPath: string, Full path of the organizational unit or its ID (required) (repeated)
  body: object, The request body. (required)
  The object takes the form of: 
  { # JSON template for Org Unit resource in Directory API.
    "kind": "admin#directory#orgUnit", # Kind of resource this is.
    "parentOrgUnitPath": "A String", # Path of parent OrgUnit
    "name": "A String", # Name of OrgUnit
    "etag": "A String", # ETag of the resource.
    "orgUnitPath": "A String", # Path of OrgUnit
    "parentOrgUnitId": "A String", # Id of parent OrgUnit
    "blockInheritance": True or False, # Should block inheritance
    "orgUnitId": "A String", # Id of OrgUnit
    "description": "A String", # Description of OrgUnit
  }
  */

  /* Function to perform rename */
  function renameOU(customerId, orgUnitPath, body){
    Logger.log(customerId + ", " + orgUnitPath + ", " + JSON.stringify(body))
    try{
      var org = AdminDirectory.Orgunits.update(customerId, orgUnitPath, body)
      }catch(e){
        Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
      }
  }

  /* Arguments */ 
  var customerId = 'my_customer';
  var oldOUname = "Education";
  var parentOrgUnitPath = "/Users/200 COGS";
  var orgUnitId = "id:03ph8a2z39wdr3v";
  var orgUnitPath = parentOrgUnitPath + "/" + oldOUname;
  var parentOrgUnitId = "id:03ph8a2z1lakohp";
  var newOUname = "255 Education";
  Logger.log(orgUnitPath);
  var body = { //# JSON template for Org Unit resource in Directory API.
    "kind": "admin#directory#orgUnit", //# Kind of resource this is.
    "parentOrgUnitPath": parentOrgUnitPath, //# Path of parent OrgUnit
    "name": newOUname, //# Name of OrgUnit
    "orgUnitPath": parentOrgUnitPath + "/" + newOUname, //# Path of OrgUnit
    "parentOrgUnitId": parentOrgUnitId, //# Id of parent OrgUnit
    "blockInheritance": false, //# Should block inheritance
    "orgUnitId": orgUnitId, //# Id of OrgUnit
  }

  /* Call Rename Function */
  Logger.log(customerId + ", " + orgUnitId + ", " + JSON.stringify(body))
  renameOU(customerId, orgUnitId, body)
}
```

I expect the result of the OU to change from "/Users/200 COGS/Education" to "/Users/200 COGS/255 Education".

The output is a parse error though:

```
[19-06-17 17:39:39:165 PDT] /Users/200 COGS/Education
[19-06-17 17:39:39:166 PDT] my_customer, id:03ph8a2z39wdr3v, {"kind":"admin#directory#orgUnit","parentOrgUnitPath":"/Users/200 COGS","name":"255 Education","orgUnitPath":"/Users/200 COGS/255 Education","parentOrgUnitId":"id:03ph8a2z1lakohp","blockInheritance":false,"orgUnitId":"id:03ph8a2z39wdr3v"}
[19-06-17 17:39:39:166 PDT] my_customer, id:03ph8a2z39wdr3v, {"kind":"admin#directory#orgUnit","parentOrgUnitPath":"/Users/200 COGS","name":"255 Education","orgUnitPath":"/Users/200 COGS/255 Education","parentOrgUnitId":"id:03ph8a2z1lakohp","blockInheritance":false,"orgUnitId":"id:03ph8a2z39wdr3v"}
[19-06-17 17:39:39:198 PDT] {"message":"API call to directory.orgunits.update failed with error: Parse Error","name":"GoogleJsonResponseException","fileName":"GSuiteOrgUnits","lineNumber":573,"stack":"\tat GSuiteOrgUnits:573 (renameOU)\n\tat GSuiteOrgUnits:600 (test_renameOU)\n","details":{"message":"Parse Error","code":400,"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"parseError","message":"Parse Error"}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `patch` endpoint you only need to pass in the fields you want to change:

```
AdminDirectory.Orgunits.patch({
  name: 'New Name'
}, customerId, ouIdOrPath);
```

Comment: Hi Eric,
Thank you for the feedback! Your suggestion works! I can see the org unit rename in the logs, although the Admin console seems to be delayed; almost an hour later and I still see the old name. I'll continue to monitor, but thanks again!

Comment: @Eric you are a savior!! thanks man! I don't know why there isn't a TRY THIS API option

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. Do not pass the Unit Path org as it is automatically adjusted by the api based on the "name" field

```
var orgUnit = new OrgUnit()
{
Name = "new name",
Description = "new description"
};
var request = service.Orgunits.Patch(orgUnit, customerId, orgUnitPath);
request.Execute();
```

Comment: Are you saying thanks for an answer? Or confirming an answer with your own experiments? Better rephrase this according to [answer] or it risks being misunderstood and being deleted as "Thanks".